# Submit Button not functioning

Tags: html, button

I was provided a template which I have changed the text.  The site displays fine but the only way to submit an email address is if I press Enter on my keyboard.

Clicking the submit button does nothing.

Can someone help?

Below is the html let me know if it is the required part that has the problem.

Thanks!

```
 <label class="hide">Email Address:</label> <input
 name="email" value="" class="txt-field"
 type="text" /> </form>
</div>
<div class="button-wrap"> <button type="submit"
value="Submit" id="submit" name="cmdSubmit"
class="link button"><span>Get Instant Access</span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Chris, where is the rest of the form HTML, like the form element itself, the action attribute, etc?

Comment: I'm a newbie to html so I would need clarification of what other code I can include here so that I can be assisted properly.  thanks jmort253

Comment: i used a webpage checker service and it stated: This form does not appear to contain a submit control so that the form data can be submitted in the normal way. Consider using an "input" element with type="submit" or type="image" or a "button" element with type="submit".

Comment: What server side language are you using? PHP, .NET, Java, Python?

Comment: Good question.  It seems the server is the most basic and possibly uses PHP.  It is from Bell Internet and provided for free to customers.  From what I see online some say it is basic html and others say it supports PHP.  I have the issue fixed though thanks to Webtecher. Thanks for taking your time to comment jmost253 I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using form then code like this

```
<label class="hide">Email Address:</label> <input
 name="email" value="" class="txt-field"
 type="text" /> </form>
</div>
<div class="button-wrap"> <input type="submit"
value="Submit" id="submit" name="cmdSubmit"
class="link button">
<span>Get Instant Access</span></button>
</div>
```

UPDATE(Sorry for my foolishness and now you can try this one)

```
<form><label class="hide">Email Address:</label> <input
 name="email" value="" class="txt-field"
 type="text" /><div class="button-wrap"> <button type="submit"
value="Submit" id="submit" name="cmdSubmit"
class="link button"><span>Get Instant Access</span></button>
</div> </form>
```

Comment: Hi Webtecher, I tried to code you put, but it only changed the button from what was on the site to a small submit button, and still does not submit by clicking.

Comment: Mind one thing always put submit button inside form tag otherwise you will need javascript to submit form with button onclick.

Comment: don't forget to click on the tick on the right side of answer

Comment: Thanks Webtecher it worked perfectly.  Thanks for taking your time to support me. I really appreciate it.